# Is there a more efficient way to write this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, virtuemart

I'm a newbie to mysql, I managed to scrape this together to get the result I wanted. Can it be coded better? Are there any security risks? Its being output in php.

```
$qwe = $product->virtuemart_product_id;    
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($qwe);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM virtuemart_product_medias where virtuemart_product_id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1');

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    
$matched = $row['virtuemart_media_id'];

$result2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM virtuemart_medias where virtuemart_media_id = ' . $matched . ' LIMIT 1');

$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);    
$matched2 = $row2['file_url_thumb'];

echo $matched2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, never use the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and relying on them is highly discouraged. Use either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
2. The above query could be rewritten as

   SELECT file_url_thumb FROM virtuemart_medias where virtuemart_media_id = (SELECT virtuemart_media_id FROM virtuemart_product_medias where virtuemart_product_id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1
3. Never do a `SELECT *`. Include only those fields in your query which you need in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether or not there is a security hole in the specific code you provided -  that depends on what other validation exists elsewhere in your program, and what you consider to be a security hole. But the way you are coding means that there definitely *could* be security holes. Let's look at your first query:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($qwe);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT *
    FROM virtuemart_product_medias
    WHERE virtuemart_product_id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1');
```

Imagine if `$qwe` is the string `0 OR 1=1 --`. The [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) only escapes certain characters such as quotes and backslashes.

> `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: `\x00`, `\n`, `\r`, `\\`, `'`, `"` and `\x1a`.

The string `0 OR 1=1 --` that I mentioned above does not contain any of these characters so it will not be affected at all by `mysql_real_escape_string`. After you substitute in the value of `$id`, the resulting SQL query will look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM virtuemart_product_medias
WHERE virtuemart_product_id = 0 OR 1=1 -- LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, this will return all rows.

Long story short: **Use PDO and parameterized queries**.

**Related**

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use one query instead of two, and select only the fields you're using, like so:

```
SELECT `file_url_thumb` FROM virtuemart_medias where virtuemart_media_id = (SELECT `virtuemart_media_id` FROM virtuemart_product_medias where virtuemart_product_id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You beat me at this. deserving +1 :)

Comment: This is a dependent sub query, which will execute once for every row returned and can be extremely nonperformant in MySQL.

Comment: Not in this particular case (LIMIT 1), and only this case is discused here.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a join;

```
SELECT a.virtuemart_media_id, b.file_url_thumb 
FROM virtuemart_product_medias a
LEFT JOIN virtuemart_medias b
  ON a.virtuemart_media_id = b.virtuemart_media_id
WHERE virtuemart_product_id = $id
LIMIT 1
```

That'll always get you the `virtuemart_media_id` and, if it exists `file_url_thumb`.

Your query has a problem also, `mysql_real_escape_string` only escapes *strings*, since you're not quoting the $id in the query, it won't be handled as a string and the escaping will not help you. As other replies point out, you should really be using mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT a.file_url_thumb 
FROM virtuemart_medias a 
LEFT JOIN virtuemart_product_medias b on a.virtuemart_media_id=b.irtuemart_media_id 
WHERE a.virtuemart_product_id=' . $id . ' LIMIT 1
```